# php: функция подключения к Базе Данных

Tags: php, mysql

Подключение к базе данных MySql выглядит так

```
 $link=mysql_connect($_DB_server,$_DB_user,$_DB_password); 
 mysql_select_db($_SystemDB_name,$link);
```

и оно появляется в коде множество раз - и в различных исходниках. Думал написать функцию ConnectDB($DB_name) и раместить его в funcs.php и подключать в необходимом исходнике (include "funcs.php")

При вызове моей функции получаю ошибку:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Если подключаться не через мою самописную функцию, то подключается нормально.
Вопрос в том почему возникает эта ошибка? И как все же написать такую функцию?

Кстати, если даже функцию объявить наверху исходника, то все равно такая же ошибка.
Т.е. не удается подключаться через функцию.

Comment: У вашего пользователя действительно нет пароля? Или может какая ошибка пробралась? Я только что создал функцию и получилось.

Comment: Да, проблема в хэндлере, вы создаете хэндлер внутри функций ConnectDB, и там же остаеться в "темноте", не увидив свет ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы создали отдельный документ под подключение к БД, то зачем еще и упаковывать в функцию? Ну, создать класс - я еще понимаю, а так напишите подключение в обычном режиме и подключайте документ там где это надо.